# How to redirect FTP to HTTP without meta tag

Tags: http, redirect, ftp

is there any change to redirect FTP link to HTTP without html meta tag? Need like this:

User visit [ftp://domain.com/?user_id={USER_ID}](ftp://domain.com/?user_id=%7BUSER_ID%7D) this url should redirect user to [https://other-domain.com/?user_id={USER_ID}](https://other-domain.com/?user_id=%7BUSER_ID%7D)

Comment: FTP does not have a native redirecting mechanism.

Comment: Is there ability to code such behaviour low level?

Comment: I don't know how I can be more clear, but no. Not unless you extend FTP and alter both client and server, at which point it's not longer FTP.

Comment: I don't need to use FTP I just need to use ftp:// protocol in url. Maybe somehow open http over ftp?

Comment: @Robin are you opening the ftp:// url with a browser? If not, what's your client?